# I want to relocate sub-pages from mediawiki from one page to another

Tags: mediawiki

My team has small wiki installation... few folks have added pages directly to home page and now we want to organize them in order... so I want to relocate those pages from home page to sub pages dedicated to that topic...

Answer (score 1):

If it's not a huge number of pages, just move them one by one. There is nothing special in subpages, they are just pages with a `/` in their name.